# Can we do simultaneous multiple operations in Redis like a Stored Procedure

Tags: lua, redis

I have a User's information which I have stored in a Hash. I have his  permission information stored in a Set.
I want to test for a condition on the Set, retrieve the Key and then fetch the actual Value using the retrieved Key from the Hash.
How can I do this?
Do I have to use Lua scripting to achieve the above goal or is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do it using multiple requests in that case. While Lua **appears** to be the way, your requirements - namely fetch a key based on the value of another key - rule out a single script since key names should be passed explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement and I couldn't find any other way to do this. Redis pipeline and transaction functions are other tools to execute multiple commands in single step but for your situation where you want to get a value and execute a command based on it, the only way remains is LUA!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use a hash to handle user information and his permissions (in the same hash). In this case, when you have a `userId` you can retrieve the permissions with one shot by using `userId` and `permissionKey`. See example below, I put the permissions as string (in your case put it as Set):

```
redis> HSET userId permissionKey "perm1, perm2, perm3"
redis> HGET userId permissionKey
"perm1, perm2, perm3"
```

Hope this help you.